# What's the difference between Seccomp and Capabilities wrt Docker environment?

Tags: docker, seccomp

I want to restrict a process(running in a docker container) from performing some function - i have 2 options, either restrict capabilities of it or i use a seccomp profile.

My question is which option to choose and under what circumstances? I am relatively new to this field, so a simple explanation would be really welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `seccomp` provides more fine-grained control than Linux `capabilities`.

If you plan to spin multiple containers and you want to avoid to replicate add/drop capabilities, `seccomp` can be a faster solution (*DRY* principle).

Although, if you just need (sic) to bind to host network, you can use the `NET_ADMIN` capabilities without the need to write down an entire `seccomp` profile.